# Raspberry Pi Tensorflow/Keras Error: Allocation of 67108864 exceeds 10% of system memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi3

Hi I am having difficulties running a ML model based on the above on Pi 3
The code is:

```
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf
# deep learning library. Tensors are just multi-dimensional arrays
import numpy as np


import time
import skimage
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv

# Import the `transform` module from `skimage`
from skimage import transform 

from skimage import data

import glob
from os import walk


fileLists = []
image28 = []
value = []

format='.jpg'

path = '/testpic'
folder = os.fsencode(path)


for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):


  for filename in filenames: 
    print (os.path.join(root,filename)) 
    if filename.endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.gif')):

        fileLists.append(skimage.data.imread(os.path.join(root,filename)))


   time1 = time.time()        
   images28  = [transform.resize(fileList, (227, 227)) for fileList in 
   fileLists]

   train_x = np.array(images28)

   new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('ml.h5')

   predictions = new_model.predict(train_x)


   for i in range(10):

time1 = time.time()

print(np.argmax(predictions[i]))

time2 = time.time()

print((time2-time1))
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   2018-11-02 09:43:34.904211: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph
>   2018-11-02 09:43:34.937663: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph
>   2018-11-02 09:43:42.740079: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph
>   2018-11-02 09:43:43.125458: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph
>   2018-11-02 09:43:43.720775: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 67108864 exceeds 10% of system memory.
>   2018-11-02 09:43:44.152943: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 67108864 exceeds 10% of system memory.
>   2018-11-02 09:43:44.298756: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 67108864 exceeds 10% of system memory.
>   2018-11-02 09:43:44.299426: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph
>   2018-11-02 09:44:08.801283: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph
>   2018-11-02 09:44:09.582225: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph
>   2018-11-02 09:44:09.788274: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 67108864 exceeds 10% of system memory.
>   2018-11-02 09:44:10.183454: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 67108864 exceeds 10% of system memory.
>   2018-11-02 09:44:28.074020: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:344] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph

After which the program is killed.

I have changed the batch size to 1 during my training process, but nothing has been fixed.

Please help.